# How can I make Netlify parse a very long private key that I put in their environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, netlify

After a ton of searching the internet and even SO, I can't find the answer to this or even anyone addressing something similar. I have a google developer private key (a very long one that includes newline characters) and I get an error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null" that comes from the file that is attempting to parse the private key. I think the problem is that the private key looks like an SSH key, it has 1732 characters and multiple newline characters. When evaluated with the newline characters it forms a multiline block with `BEGIN` then 26 lines of 64 characters each (except the last) and the `END` line.

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIB ... c4L+SIi89q1aDDD/o=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

and no matter how I attempt to make that key work I always get that error.

My code that grabs this key:

```js
// google-config.js

module.exports = {
  devCreds: {
    type: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_TYPE,
    project_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    private_key_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
    private_key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    client_email: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    auth_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_URI,
    token_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url:
      process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL,
    client_x509_cert_url: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL,
  },
};
```

and the code that uses the key...

```
const { devCreds } = require('./google-config');

export async function addRow(data) {
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(formDataDestinationSheet);
  return doc.useServiceAccountAuth(devCreds, error => {
    doc.addRow(1, data, error => {
      if (error) console.log(error);
    });
    if (error) console.log(error);
  });
}
```

To be sure that I am getting the private key I log it out when the app starts to see that it is what I expect it to be. This may not be smart but when you're frustrated you'll try anything. Obviously I'll be getting a new key very shortly.

So here's what I've tried...
Around the whole thing... double quotes, single quotes, back-ticks, and no quotes at all.
I also tried escaping the `\` in each of the above scenarios like `\\n` at each new-line character. Somewhere I read that someone had success in replacing the newline characters with an underscore (but they were dealing with an actual ssh key so...¯\_(ツ)_/¯...) I'm obviously starting to grasp at straws here.

In most of the above scenarios, this works on my box just fine. The ways it didn't work on my box are with back-ticks and with escaping the newline character. The back-ticks approach gives me the same error that I get from running it on Netlify.

Really hoping someone has an idea of what I might do to fix this.

Comment: My workaround, for now, is to remove the newline characters from the env variable and create a function in my app that puts them back where they belong after getting it from Netlify. Shouldn't have to do this but it's working for now.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve this issue and found an answer on [this blogpost](https://www.dferber.de/how-to-use-google-cloud-platform-from-netlify/):

```js
credentials: {
  client_email: process.env.GCP_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  private_key: process.env.GCP_PRIVATE_KEY.split("\\n").join("\n")
}
```

It looks like netlify escape the newlines for you...